# How to integrate a LLVM pass (instrument part + runtime lib part) completely in LLVM?

Tags: clang, llvm, integration, clang++

I want to do something with clang, and now I have written a pass that will instrument the source code(insert some function calls in source code), just like:

```
int main(){
     ...
     func1(para1, para2 ...);//func1 is inserted by pass, which is defined in my runtime library.
     ...
     return 0;
}
```

I have finished all the things above, and generally, if we want to run our pass,
we just do as follows:

1. `clang++ -S -emit-llvm xx.cpp -o xx.ll`
2. `opt -load xx.so -xx xx.ll -o xx.ll`
3. `... -o xx.o`
4. `... xx.o -L/runtime_library_path -lxx(.a or .so) -o xxx`

But now, I want to finish all the steps above by passing a **flag** to clang.
eg : `clang++ -useMypassAndrtlib xx.cpp` ,and then it will run my pass during compile period and link my runtime library during link period.

Until now, I have achieved half of my goals.
I can run my pass just by passing a flag to `clang`, but i still need to have emplicit link to my `rt-lib`.
eg : `clang++ -useMyPass xx.cpp -L/runtime_library_path -lmyrtlib -o xxx`

So what should I do to integrate my pass (include rt-lib part) in LLVM completely?

which source file I should modify? Modify what?
I just want to use "**clang++ -useMyPassAndrtlib xx.cpp**" to run my pass and use my rt-lib automatically.

Comment: Hi, I ran into the same issue. Did you figured out how to solve this?

Comment: I solved this problem last year. As for the first part, you need to do some work to register your pass in LLVM including adding the options for driver, frontend and backend respectively. The specific steps can be found on Google. For the second part, you need to change the Clang.cpp to add the extra option (eg: -lyour_rtlib) when you found the target option (-use_yourpass) in the driver options set.

Comment: The first part may be a bit complex, any incorrect step can lead to strange error. In the second part, you need to put your runtime lib (eg: your_rtlib.so) in LLVM_src/build/lib. Btw, are you a chinese student? My English is not so good, it is hard for me to answer the question clearly. If you have any doubts, you can add my wechat :)

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot I understand that.

Comment: I will try those steps